# Kendo Grid filter menu to check filtered values when applying filter with code

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid and I'm applying a custom filter on 'adUser' column in certain condition
like this

```
var filterKeyWord = "m.owen"
grid.dataSource.filter({ field: "adUser", operator: "eq", value: filterKeyWord});
```

the filter gets applied as expected, but on UI side filter is empty and user can't tell what condition was applied to grid filter. Am I doing something wrong? Is this the way it should work or should I add something to see filter keyword("m.owen") displayed in filter search box and dropdown(as checked)?

Comment: You've filtered the datasource, not the grid. Maybe you can set the same filter values in the event `FilterMenuInit`: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/filtermenuinit